# Sql server join/subselect question

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I have two tables in the database

```
Team:Id(int PK), Name(nvarchar)
```

and

```
Player:Id(int PK), Name(nvarchar), Age(int), TeamId(int FK)
```

I also have the following classes

```
class Team
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

and

```
class Player
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public int Age{get;set;}
   public int TeamId{get;set;}
}
```

and

```
class TeamInfo
{
   public Team Team{get;set;}
   public List<Player> Players{get;set;}
}
```

I want to extract from the databse a `List<TeamInfo>`.
I am using Ado.net, no ef or linq2sql... and I am asking what is the best way to query the db?

Right now I get all teams and for each team I query the table players with a join but for sure it's not the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should read all info from database with `join` query:

```
SELECT 
       Team.Id as TeamId,
       Team.Name as TeamName,
       Player.Id as PlayerId,
       Player.Name as PlayerId,
FROM Team INNER JOIN Player on Team.Id = Player.TeamId
```

Use this query as part of `SqlCommand` and get data into `DataTable`. Then:

```
var teamInfos = datatable.Rows
                    .Cast<DataRow>()
                    .GroupBy(dr => (int) dr["TeamId"])
                    .Select(t => new TeamInfo
                       {
                           Team = new Team{ Id = t.Key, 
                                            Name = (string)t.First["TeamName"] },
                           Players = t.Select(p => new PlayerInfo {
                                      Id = (int)p["PlayerId"],
                                      Name = (int)p["PlayerName"],
                                      // other player fields here
                                 })
                                 .ToList()
                       });
```

**NOTE:** Probably you need a `LEFT` join here instead of `INNER` since you won't get teams without players otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

i'd create an sp in sql server with the parameters @teamid, then execute the sp for the team and get the player info

```
create procedure [dbo].[TeamPlayers]
as

@teamid int
begin

    set nocount on;

select
    t.ID as TeamID,
    t.name,
    p.ID as PlayerID,
    p.name,
    p.age
from dbo.Player p
    inner join Team t
        on p.TeamID=t.ID
where t.ID=@teamid


end
```